# State Transition Table for a Finite State Machine

Tags: state-machine

I would like to ask for your help in understanding this question:

A finite state machine M with 1-bit input and 1-bit output and the output is given by these logic functions:

```
O(0) = 0
O(1) = I(0).I(1)
O(t) = I(t).I(t-1)+I(t).I(t-2)+I(t-1).I(t-2), t>=2
```

The question asks to show the transition table of M with minimum number of states. I(t) and O(t) denote the the values of input and output at time t.
i really do not understand how to consider the time factor in building the state transition table.
Also, if it happens that you know some resources (books, ..) that will help me to understand and solve questions like this one, would you suggest some of them?

Comment: What does `.` mean?

Comment: @chepner it means _and_